# Multiple entries of MSXML 4.0 parser

Tags: .net, parsing, windows-installer, installation

I have 5 different entries on my Add/Remove programs list for MXSML 4.0 Parser. Below are those,

- MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB954430)
- MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB973688)
- MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser
- MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser (KB973685)
- MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser (KB2758694)

So Is there any way to check which applications are dependent on these MSXML versions on WIN 7 machine?

Or Can it be fine if i remove those entries blindly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, no way as far as i know of. I wouldn't suggest  uninstalling any of these versions. Doing so might break other applications which are dependent on these.